# Unity Namespaces aren't available

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I wanted to continue coding where I left after sleeping, but suddenly as I open my Code in Visual Studio and tried to work on my code while having *using UnityEngine.UI* or *using UnityEngine.EventSystems* standing at the top, it just says that the type or namespace *"UI"* or *"Eventsystems"* doesn't exist in the namespace *"UnityEngine"*. And I also can't use *using TMPro*. I don't know if thats all I can't use.

I've now just restarted my pc, reselected Visual Studio 2022 17.2.5 in Unitys external tools and uptaded Visual Studio and it sill doesn't work.

Maybe it's important to know that restarting my Unity project isn't working.

How to fix that and how to prevent it from happening again?

Comment: what type of project did you create?

Comment: Have you tried regenerating the project c# project files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Unity and go to **Window > Package Manager**. In the **Package Manager** window, select **In Project** from the dropdown as shown below.
[image]

In the list of packages, find **Visual Studio Editor** and update it to the latest version.

Close all Visual Studio windows, go to **Edit > Preferences > External Tools**, and regenerate project files (In your case, the **External Script Editor** is **Visual Studio**).
[image]

Reopen any script in your project and the error should disappear.

Comment: Strangely I still needed to re-enter MonoBehaviour but for the rest it work, thanks